# How to master pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, resource

I'm looking for methods and resources (such as music along with their text - audio books) to improve my German pronunciation, other than talking to a native speaker.

***EDIT***:

I'm given advice by others a lot, I'm looking for resources now. For instance, [take a look at this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/4/techniques-for-improving-pronunciation).

Comment: You know how they say... Practice makes perfect! :P

Comment: http://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/audio ^^ (ich glaub, das ist zu langweilig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Radio station [Deutschlandfunk](http://www.dradio.de/dlf/) offers a text transcript along with some of it's audio content, like in this example: [radio feature about the project "Zeitungszeugen"](http://www.dradio.de/dkultur/sendungen/fazit/1662526/) (click the headline to hear the audio)

Answer (score 1):

Basically I see the following possible approaches:

- listen to music and read the lyrics (as you already wrote)
- speak with native speakers (not always available)
- watching movies

Of these three possibilities, watching movies was the one that helped me the most. The benefit from watching movies is, you can get an impression of the culture, too.

Movies and music can be obtained through the normal channels, e.g. Amazon.
In a foreign land immigrants tend to build groups that meet regularly. Try to find native speakers at these meetings.

Comment: I improved my English quite a bit by listening to podcasts. If Gigili talks a bit about his/her interests, I maybe can recommend some German podcasts.

Comment: @0x6d64: What are the categories which you have podcast about? I'm interested in fairy tales, as for scientific texts: mathematical texts or something related to computer science!

Comment: As for computer science: Have a look at Chaosradio Express (https://wiki.chaosradio.ccc.de/Chaosradio_Express) or Chaosradio (which I don't like too much, because of rather strange listener calls).

Comment: Other than that I listen to podcasts about scepticism, media and internet culture/politics. Unfortunately for you, the best story-telling podcast I know (the Moth) is in English.

Comment: @0x6d64: Thank you, [CRE](http://cre.fm/cre016) is perfect but unfortunately the source is not included, I need to follow the text while it's being read by someone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2305/discussion-between-0x6d64-and-gigili)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend two specific audio books, since I already mentioned them in the chat and I immediately thought about them when I read the [linked chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2305/discussion-between-0x6d64-and-gigili), and Gigili likes fairy tales.

The books are written by Kai Meyer and made as audio play by Zaubermond. They are about the Brothers Grimm as investigators in a setting that is a mixture of historical Germany and fiction. Goethe is involved in both stories, and you'll likely see him differently afterwards. There are a lot of great speakers involved and I really liked the books. Most German is well-spoken, it has a lot of very different speakers (so a lot of variation), and some dialects too.

I'd recommend to start with [Die Geisterseher](http://www.amazon.de/Die-Geisterseher-Kai-Meyer/dp/3936558000/), though I had [Die Winterprinzessin](http://www.amazon.de/Die-Winterprinzessin-Kai-Meyer/dp/B003YXJHRM/) first, but Die Winterprinzessin has several references to the events in Die Geisterseher.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to audio resources with well spoken German and repeat the texts yourself. Record your voice and compare it to the original speakers.